# When using setFetchMode in Hiberate criteria how do I set a restriction on the oneToMany table

Tags: hibernate, criteria

I'm struggling to create a Hibernate criteria query that uses setFetchMode(... SELECT) and places a restriction on the returned child records. If I use a creteAlias as recommended it produces an inner join thereby making accurate pagination all but impossible.

The code would be like:-

```
Criteria criteria = this.getSession().createCriteria(Mother.class);
criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("title"))
// .createAlias("children", "childrenAlias") had to remove
.add(Restrictions.eq("childAge", "5")) // how do I reference childAge?
.setMaxResults(details.getMaxRows())
.setFirstResult(details.getStart())
.setFetchMode("children", FetchMode.SELECT);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

God knows where I was at when I posted this. Thought I'd post the answer to tidy up.

The code I was missing was the following:-

```
Criterion child = Restrictions.eq("childAlias.childName", "Albert");
criteria.createAlias("children", "childAlias", CriteriaSpecification.INNER_JOIN);
criteria.add(child);
```

Comment: since 
    ``CriteriaSpecification.INNER_JOIN`` 
is deprecated, you should use [``JoinType.INNER_JOIN``](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/javadocs/org/hibernate/sql/JoinType.html#INNER_JOIN) instead